# Schema.org: How to use isAccessoryOrSparePartFor in JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org

I'm trying to declare products in JSON-LD for schema.org. I came across isAccessoryOrSparePartFor. So what do I put inside this tag? Schema.org says it should be a Product - but do I really have to put full product-declarations in it? Could I put URLs or EANs of the sparepart-products in it?

Answer (score 1):

For the [`isAccessoryOrSparePartFor` property](http://schema.org/isAccessoryOrSparePartFor), a `Product` value is *expected*, but not required.

[From the Schema.org documentation](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected):

> **Expected types vs text.** When browsing the schema.org types, you will notice that many properties have "expected types". This means that the value of the property can itself be an embedded item (see section 1d: embedded items). But this is not a requirement—it's fine to include just regular text or a URL. […]

Of course, some consumers might not support other values than the expected ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a minimal product declaration with only @context, @type and the product URL as id.

Example:

```
  isAccessoryOrSparePartFor: [
    {
      '@context': 'http://schema.org',
      '@type': 'Product',
      id: UNIQUE_PRODUCT_ID_1'
    },
    {
      '@context': 'http://schema.org',
      '@type': 'Product',
      id: UNIQUE_PRODUCT_ID_2'
    },
    ...
   ]
```

You can check use [Google's testing tool for structured data](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) to validate.